# How to do asset versioning when the static files are hosted on s3 with node.js?

Tags: node.js, caching, amazon-s3, gruntjs, static-assert

We are building a feature to allow users to upload their static html/javascript and we will serve the static content.

When someone makes requests

`https://oursite.com/[insert_username]/index.html`

or

`https://oursite.com/[insert_username]/cat-photo.jpg`

We will grab the latest file from s3 and serve the file to the client. These files are cached on the client-side.

We want to be able to bust the client cache immediately as soon as a user updates their static files.

A common answer is to give it a unique hash like `index.123abc.html` but the problem is this:

Let's say `index.html` references `<img src="/cat-photo.jpg">` and the user uploads a new `cat-photo.gif`.  how do I always respond with the cached index.html but the latest `cat-photo.gif`; As I cannot modify the content of `index.html` to reference to a `cat-photo.123abc.gif`